# Ros NXT question

Tags: nxt, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am very very new in Ros and I want to connect a NXT robot.
My question is **do i need to install Ros and Ros-NXT or is ROS-NXT-Electric enough?**

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 on a VM.

Thanks for your time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218189/ros-nxt-question/) by [Kzr](https://answers.ros.org/users/24034/kzr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-09-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There hasn't been NXT support for a long time, but you can certainly use it with Electric. I would recommend, however, that you first try to use some simulated robots in Gazebo. The PR2 robot's tutorials are rather helpful.

http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_gazebo

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2015-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0